# Google Big Query SQL to extract numeric ID from string

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How do I write a SQL Query in Google Big Query to extract numeric ID from a string like these:

**Example 1:**
Column Value: "http://www.google.com/abc/eeq/entity/32132"

Desired Extraction: 32132

**Example 2:**
Column Value: "http://www.google.com/abc/eeq/entity/32132/ABC/2138"

Desired Extraction: 32132

**Example 3:**
Column Value: "http://www.google.com/abc/eeq/entity/32132http://www.google.com/abc/eeq/entity/32132"

Desired Extraction: 32132

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below example for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT "http://www.google.com/abc/eeq/entity/32132" url UNION ALL
  SELECT "http://www.google.com/abc/eeq/entity/32132/ABC/2138" UNION ALL
  SELECT "http://www.google.com/abc/eeq/entity/32132http://www.google.com/abc/eeq/entity/32132" 
)
SELECT url, REGEXP_EXTRACT(url, r'\d+') extracted_id 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with output

```
Row url                                                                             extracted_id     
1   http://www.google.com/abc/eeq/entity/32132                                          32132    
2   http://www.google.com/abc/eeq/entity/32132/ABC/2138                                 32132    
3   http://www.google.com/abc/eeq/entity/32132http://www.google.com/abc/eeq/entity/32132    32132
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`regexp_extract()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#regexp_extract).  To get the first series of digits in the string:

```
select regexp_extract(col, '[0-9]+')
```